In SQL, how does one get the first occurrence of every column value change for a table?
The title may be confusing here but I can explain it better here. If I have a SQL table that adds a new row for every ID and does so 2x daily regardless of what changes (or doesn't) like below:



ID
Status
Time




1
Open
2022-07-01 12:00


1
Open
2022-07-01 18:00


1
In Progress
2022-07-02 12:00


1
Open
2022-07-02 18:00


1
Closed
2022-07-03 12:00



How can I return the following from that table:



ID
Status
Time




1
Open
2022-07-01 12:00


1
In Progress
2022-07-02 12:00


1
Open
2022-07-02 18:00


1
Closed
2022-07-03 12:00



I have tried to make do with a basic multi column ROW_NUMBER() over the ID and Status fields but obviously that acts more like a DISTINCT clause and so it skips out on rows where it returns back to an old status weeks later. Is there a way to do this using LAG or LEAD maybe? I figure that's the most promising option but I'm at a loss on how to do something this complex using just SQL. Unfortunately I don't have a time column for status changes specifically. Any ideas?
The query I have tried is below:
WITH newtab AS (
SELECT ID, Status, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Status) as Ranking
  FROM table1 
)

SELECT * 
FROM newtab
WHERE Ranking = 1


"I have tried to make ..."  So where is this query that you have tried???  We don't see it posted here.

I just edited the post, I didn't include it originally because it seems to me that the ROW_NUMBER route is a dead end

Use the LAG function to compare the current row's Status with the previous row's Status within each ID partition. This way, you can identify when the Status changes and filter out the rows where the Status has not changed.
Like this:
WITH change_points AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    Status,
    Time,
    LAG(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Time) AS prev_status
  FROM
    table1
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Status,
  Time
FROM
  change_points
WHERE
  prev_status IS NULL OR prev_status != Status
ORDER BY
  ID,
  Time;

change_points CTE:
Use the LAG function to get the Status of the previous row within each ID partition, ordered by Time.
The LAG(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Time) generates a new column prev_status which holds the value of the Status from the previous row for the same ID.
Main Query:
Select the rows where prev_status is NULL (which means it's the first row for that ID) or where the prev_status is different from the current Status.
Order the results by ID and Time to get the desired sequence.
This will give you the first occurrence of every Status change for each ID.

Are you sure ROW_NUMBER() works without ORDER BY?  I think ROW_NUMBER() will work just fine.
WITH newtab AS (
SELECT ID, Status, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Status, CAST(TIME AS DATE) ORDER BY Time) as Ranking
  FROM table1 
)

SELECT * 
FROM newtab
WHERE Ranking = 1

